# Average Energy of a coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

The question is relating to a previous problem concerning the harmonic oscillator.

**Determine the average energy < E > in a coherent state |alpha>.**

From my understanding the expectation of the energy would simply mean calculating 
< alpha| H | alpha>. Where < H > = < T > + < V > for a harmonic oscillator. Is my approach valid?

I am confused as to what role the coherent state plays in this and whether this really is the average energy.

Comment: The role the coherent state plays is that you will need to express $| \alpha \rangle$ as a sum over the number states $| n \rangle$ to express the action of the Hamiltonian on it. I don't remember the formula off the top of my head--it's not too rough to derive, but it's probably expected that you'll just start with it.

Comment: It's quite simple, you have that a|alpha> = alpha|alpha>, therefore the expectation value of a-dagger a will be |alpha|^2

Comment: Yes thank you I have solved it up to |alpha|^2. Could you please elaborate on what |alpha|^2 actually represents? Thanks.

Comment: @CountIblis: oh duh of course. I don't know what I was thinking of--maybe overlap between two coherent states.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding the expectation of the energy would simply mean
>   calculating  < alpha| H | alpha>. Where < H > = < T > + < V > for a
>   harmonic oscillator. Is my approach valid?

Yes. This is a valid approach. This is what is meant by the expectation value of the energy.